# Asynchronous Jobs with large waiting time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, web-worker

So basically I have two instances, my Webserver and my Worker instance both deployed on Ruby on Rails using AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

I just added a new job on my worker instance so it can create a xlsx file containing all db records from a certain model. This task usually takes up to 40 minutes to complete, the problem is when this job is ejecuting request usually stop working until the process is finished (including the healthcheck link).

How can I make this job be independent from other request so it dosen't affect the ability of my worker instance to handle requests?

Request arrive via SQS and handle by a controller (default Worker ElasticBeanstak profile) which determine what to do.

XLSX files are currently handle by the following Job:

```
class NotifyJob < ApplicationJob
    require 'json'
    require 'date'
    require 'aws-sdk'
    require 'rubyXL'

    queue_as :notify

    def perform(type)
      case type
        when 'doctor'
          start = Time.now
          doc = doctores
          S3.put_object({:bucket => 'cadigen-images', :key => 'doctor.xlsx', :body => doc.stream, :content_length => doc.stream.string.length, :content_type => doc.content_type.to_s, acl: "public-read"})
          after = Time.now
          link = Aws::S3::Object.new("cadigen-images","doctor.xlsx",:client => S3).public_url
          NotificationMailer.finished('Relacion Doctores',time(start,after),Doctor.count,"<a href='#{link}'>doctor.xlsx</a>","frhectorin@gmail.com").deliver_now
        when 'cadi'
          start = Time.now
          cadi = cadis
          S3.put_object({:bucket => 'cadigen-images', :key => 'cadi.xlsx', :body => cadi.stream, :content_length => cadi.stream.string.length, :content_type => cadi.content_type.to_s, acl: "public-read"})
          after = Time.now
          link = Aws::S3::Object.new("cadigen-images","cadi.xlsx",:client => S3).public_url
          NotificationMailer.finished('Relacion CADIs',time(start,after),Cadi.count,"<a href='#{link}'> cadi.xlsx</a>","frhectorin@gmail.com").deliver_now
        when 'conferencia'
          start = Time.now
          conf = conferencia
          S3.put_object({:bucket => 'cadigen-images', :key => 'conferencia.xlsx', :body => conf.stream, :content_length => conf.stream.string.length, :content_type => conf.content_type.to_s, acl: "public-read"})
          after = Time.now
          link = Aws::S3::Object.new("cadigen-images","conferencia.xlsx",:client => S3).public_url
          NotificationMailer.finished('Relacion Conferencia',time(start,after) ,Conferencia.count,"<a href='#{link}'>conferencia.xlsx</a>","frhectorin@gmail.com").deliver_now
        else
          render status: 500
      end
    end

    def time(start,ending)
      if start != ending
        medidas=["año","mes","dia","hora","minuto","segundo"]
        array=[1970,1,1,0,0,0]
        text = ""
        Time.at(ending-start).utc.to_a.take(6).reverse.each_with_index do |k,i|
          text = "#{text} #{I18n.translate medidas[i].to_sym, count: k-array[i]}"
        end
        text = text.strip.squish
        puts text
        pos = text.rindex(" ",(text.rindex(" ")-1))
        unless pos.nil?
          text = text.insert(pos," y")
        end
        text = text.strip.squish
      else
        "0 segundos"
      end
    end

    def doctores
      workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
      worksheet = workbook[0]

      worksheet.add_cell(0, 0,'ID')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 1,'Cuenta')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 2,'Titulo')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 3,'Nombre')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 4,'Email')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 5,'Pais')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 6,'Verificado')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 7,'Autoriza Envio de Emails')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 8,'Activo')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 9,'Bounce')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 10,'Complains')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 11,'CADIS')

      doctores = Doctor.order(:id)

      doctores.each_with_index do |doctor,i|
        i=i+1
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 0, doctor.id)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 1, doctor.cuenta)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 2, doctor.titulo)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 3, doctor.nombre)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 4, doctor.email)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 5, doctor.pais)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 6, doctor.verified ? 'Si':'No')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 7, doctor.email_authorized ? 'Si':'No')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 8, doctor.active ? 'Si':'No')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 9, doctor.bounce ? 'Si':'No')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 10, doctor.complains ? 'Si':'No')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 11, doctor.count)
      end

      return workbook

      #send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "doctor.xlsx", disposition: 'attachment'

    end

    def conferencia
      workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
      worksheet = workbook[0]

      worksheet.add_cell(0, 0,'ID')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 1,'Conferencia')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 2,'Conferencista')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 3,'Numero de Conferencia')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 4,'Fecha')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 5,'Tema')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 6,'Patrocinador')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 7,'Estatus')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 8,'Acreditaciones')

      conferencias = Conferencia.order(:id)

      conferencias.each_with_index do |conferencia,i|
        i=i+1
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 0, conferencia.id)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 1, conferencia.conferencia)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 2, conferencia.conferencista)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 3, conferencia.numero_conferencia)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 4, conferencia.fecha.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 5, conferencia.tema)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 6, conferencia.patrocinador)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 7, conferencia.status ? 'Acreditada':'Sin Acreditar')
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 8, conferencia.count)
      end

      return workbook

      #send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "doctor.xlsx", disposition: 'attachment'

    end

    def cadis
      workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
      worksheet = workbook[0]

      worksheet.add_cell(0, 0,'ID')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 1,'Numero de CADI')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 2,'Email')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 3,'Cuenta')
      worksheet.add_cell(0, 4,'Conferencia')

      cadis = Cadi.order(:id)

      cadis.each_with_index do |cadi,i|
        i=i+1
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 0, cadi.id)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 1, cadi.numero_cadi)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 2, cadi.doctor.email)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 3, cadi.doctor.cuenta)
        worksheet.add_cell(i, 4, cadi.conferencia.conferencia)
      end

      return workbook

      #send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "doctor.xlsx", disposition: 'attachment'

    end
end
```

And call using

```
NotifyJob.perform_now(type)
```

My queue handler is [active-elastic-job](https://github.com/tawan/active-elastic-job)

Comment: Sounds like `perform_now` [is synchronous](http://api.rubyonrails.org/?q=activejob). You probably need to call `perform_later` instead.

Comment: Did, it enqueued de job but didn't actually start ( wait 1 hour)

Comment: That means your queue is reporting back as “busy.”

Comment: The problem is that it's always busy because health checks are every 30 seconds